# How Dangerous is This Faster `strlen`?

Tags: c

`strlen` is a fairly simple function, and it is obviously O(n) to compute.  However, I have seen a few approaches that operate on *more than one character at a time*.  See example 5 [here](http://www.azillionmonkeys.com/qed/asmexample.html) or this approach [here](http://www.strchr.com/optimized_strlen_function).  The basic way these work is by reinterpret-casting the `char const*` buffer to a `uint32_t const*` buffer and then checking four bytes at a time.

Personally, my gut reaction is that this is a segfault-waiting-to-happen, since I might dereference up to three bytes outside valid memory.  However, this solution seems to hang around, and it seems curious to me that something so obviously broken has stood the test of time.

I think this comprises UB for two reasons:

1. Potential dereference outside valid memory
2. Potential dereference of unaligned pointer

(<sub><sup>Note that there is not an aliasing issue; one might think the `uint32_t` is aliased as an incompatible type, and code after the `strlen` (such as code that might change the string) could run out of order to the `strlen`, but it turns out that `char` is an explicit exception to strict aliasing</sup></sub>).

But, how likely is it to fail in practice?  At minimum, I think there needs to be `3` bytes padding after the string literal data section, malloc needs to be `4`-byte or larger aligned (actually the case on most systems), and `malloc` needs to allocate `3` extra bytes.  There are other criteria related to aliasing.  This is all fine for compiler implementations, which create their own environments, but **how frequently are these conditions met on modern hardware for user code?**

Comment: Seems there is nothing wrong with it (but I would trust the library function; or avoid strlen() if possible)

Comment: Remember that undefined behaviour can still be defined by the implementation.

Comment: BTW: take a look at libc implementations. They are non-trivial (like this one) and take care of differences between platforms. Also: do some code-profiling. If strlen() is the limiting factor, you are doing something worong, IMnsvHO.

Comment: I don't see how any of those 4-byte approaches to `strlen()` can be any faster. For starters, `test` and `cmp` are some of the most expensive operations you can do in any architecture as far as I know, and you are not economizing on them one bit. You are also adding a lot of operations to the process that are not particularly necessary, all for the sake of copying 4 bytes of memory at a time to a local variable, another thing that theres no point in doing at all. Remember theres L1 and L2 caches envolved, so its not like you are buffering the string from some slow media.

Comment: @Havenard: you can combine the tests in the unrolled case. For example, the first source uses `#define hasNulByte(x) ((x - 0x01010101) & ~x & 0x80808080)` on the `uint32_t`, which is equivalent to the more-brute-force way done in the second example.

Comment: Theres one thing you can do that is faster than any `strlen()` implementation you can come up with. You can simply keep track of your string length.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The technique is valid, and you will not avoid it if you call our C library `strlen`. If that library is, for instance, a recent version of the GNU C library (at least on certain targets), it does the same thing.

The key to make it work is to ensure that the pointer is aligned properly. If the pointer is aligned, the operation will read beyond the end of the string surely enough, but not into an adjacent page.  If the null terminating byte is within one word of the end of a page, then that last word will be accessed without touching the subsequent page.

It certainly isn't well-defined behavior in C, and so it carries the burden of careful validation when ported from one compiler to another. It also triggers false positives from out-of-bounds access detectors like Valgrind.

Valgrind had to be patched to work around Glibc doing this. Without the patches, you get nuisance errors such as this:

```
==13669== Invalid read of size 8
==13669==    at 0x411D6D7: __wcslen_sse2 (wcslen-sse2.S:59)
==13669==    by 0x806923F: length_str (lib.c:2410)
==13669==    by 0x807E61A: string_out_put_string (stream.c:997)
==13669==    by 0x8075853: obj_pprint (lib.c:7103)
==13669==    by 0x8084318: vformat (stream.c:2033)
==13669==    by 0x8081599: format (stream.c:2100)
==13669==    by 0x408F4D2: (below main) (libc-start.c:226)
==13669==  Address 0x43bcaf8 is 56 bytes inside a block of size 60 alloc'd
==13669==    at 0x402BE68: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==13669==    by 0x8063C4F: chk_malloc (lib.c:1763)
==13669==    by 0x806CD79: sub_str (lib.c:2653)
==13669==    by 0x804A7E2: sysroot_helper (txr.c:233)
==13669==    by 0x408F4D2: (below main) (libc-start.c:226)
```

Glibc is using SSE instructions to do calculate `wcslen` eight bytes at a time (instead of four, the width of `wchar_t`). In doing so, it is accessing at offset 56 in a block that is 60 bytes wide. However, note that this access could never straddle a page boundary: the address is divisible by 8.

If you're working in assembly language, you don't have to think twice about the technique.

In fact, the technique is used quite bit in some optimized audio codecs that I work with (targetting ARM), which feature a lot of hand-written assembly language in the Neon instruction set.

I noticed it when running Valgrind on code which integrated these codecs, and contacted the vendor. They explained that it was just a harmless loop optimization technique; I went through the assembly language and convinced myself they were right.

Comment: Accept, because this is essentially the use case: the platform knows what it's doing, with examples. See also @nneoneo's answer for why you probably don't want to do this yourself.

Answer (score 3):

(1) can definitely happen. There's nothing preventing you from taking the `strlen` of a string near the end of an allocated page, which could result in an access past the end of allocated memory and a nice big crash.  As you note, this could be mitigated by padding all your allocations, but then you have to have any libraries do the same. Worse, you have to arrange for the linker and OS to always add this padding (remember the OS passes argv[] in a static memory buffer somewhere). The overhead of doing this isn't worth it.

(2) also definitely happens. Earlier versions of ARM processors generate data aborts on unaligned accesses, which either cause your program to die with a bus error (or halt the CPU if you're running bare-metal), or force a *very* expensive trap through the kernel to handle the unaligned access. These earlier ARM chips are still in wide use in older cellphones and embedded devices. Later ARM processors synthesize multiple word accesses to deal with unaligned accesses, but this will result in overall slower performance since you basically double the number of memory loads you need to do.

Many current ("modern") PICs and embedded microprocessors lack the logic to handle unaligned accesses, and may behave unpredictably or even nonsensically when given unaligned addresses (I've personally seen chips that will just mask off the bottom bits, which would give incorrect answers, and others that will just give garbage results with unaligned accesses).

So, this is ridiculously dangerous to use in anything that should be remotely portable. Please, please, please do not use this code; use the libc strlen. It will usually be faster (optimized for your platform properly) and will make your code portable. The last thing you want is for your code to subtly and unexpectedly break in some situation (string near the end of an allocation) or on some new processor.

Comment: While I agree that no responsible programmer would ever want to use something like this, I suspect that calling it "ridiculously dangerous" is probably an exaggeration.

Comment: I disagree. A function which comes with a list of unusual limitations (aligned input, must not be too close to the end of an allocation), and which could just break silently on some platforms, is the very definition of "ridiculously dangerous". Sure, speed is good and often necessary, but if you're going for speed at least use assembly so it is obvious your code isn't portable.

Comment: (Not to mention that on some platforms, the unaligned access penalty is so severe that this code will probably end up being significantly *slower* than the naive approach!)

Comment: Some platforms handle unaligned accesses _in software_ (e.g. ARM9). I haven't benchmarked it, but I would very surprised if it wasn't dramatically slower than than the naive solution.

Comment: @nneonneo: I'm not defending the technique, but I'd bet money that you could deploy it (even in high-volume production code) and get away with it for years without it ever crashing, so it doesn't fit my definition of "ridiculously dangerous" -- but again, I'm still not saying you should use it!  (The unaligned input penalty needn't be a problem, either, as the "fast strlen" code could check for it and synch itself up on a word boundary, albeit at the cost of slower startup which would kill its performance for the majority of short strings.)

Answer (score 1):

Donald Knuth, a person who wrote 3+ volumes on clever algorithms said: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil".

*strlen()* is used a lot, so it really should be fast. Riffing on wildplasser's remark, "I would trust the library function", what makes you think that the library function works byte at a time? Or is slow?

The title may give folks the impression that the code you suggest is faster than the standard system library *strlen()*, but I think what you mean  is that it is faster than a naive *strlen()* which probably doesn't get used, anyway.

I compiled a simple C program and looked on my 64-bit system which uses GNU's glibc function. The code I saw was pretty sophisticated and looks pretty fast in terms of working with register width rather than byte at a time. The code I saw for *strlen()* is written in assembly language so there probably aren't junk instructions as you might get if this were compiled C code. What I saw was [rtld-strlen.S](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/sysdeps/x86_64/rtld-strlen.S). This code also unrolls loops to reduce the overhead in looping.

Before you think you can do better on strlen, you should look at that code, or the corresponding code for your particular architecture, and register size.

And if you do write your own strlen, benchmark it against the existing implementation.

And obviously, if you use the system strlen, then it is probably correct and you don't have to worry about invalid memory references as a result of an optimization in the code.

Comment: I like how you pointed out that standard implementation is not necessarily naive as OP assumes, with proof from inspecting compiled assembly code.

Answer (score 0):

I agree it's a bletcherous technique, but I suspect it's likely to work most of the time.  It's only a segfault if the string happens to be right up against the end of your data (or stack) segment.  The vast majority of strings (wheher statically or dynamically allocated) won't be.

But you're right, to *guarantee* it working you'd need some guarantee that all strings were padded somehow, and your list of shims looks about right.

If alignment is a problem, you could take care of that in the fast strlen implementation; you wouldn't have to run around trying to align all strings.

(But of course, if your problem is that you're spending too much time scanning strings, the right fix is not to desperately try to make string scanning faster, but to rig things up so that you don't have to scan so many strings in the first place...)